# Are there any source or article to make an android version of a website?

Tags: android, ios, web

I searching  for an article how make android or ios version of a website for example apk format in android for a website
I dont want to use bootstrap html or etc, I just want to try practice of usind java to make android version or swift to ios version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think without HTML coding u can't develop the GUI of any web site. but if u want to create apk file which run on web page also then u might be use (ionic, cordova) framework to create cross platform App which also run on Web browser and it will also give feel like app on web browser.